# My project suddenly will not allow me to connect any IBOutlets to any ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, storyboard

I currently have a project that initially had 2 view controllers, with IBOutlets. I can drag them to their respective ViewController files and do the codes accordingly. I then had to make new Views identical to 1 of the already made views. However, this time, I cannot connect my IBOutlets to the code at all.

I think the origin of my error is when I copy pasted the IBOutlets from the one view that I needed into the other views. However, I did everything make sure that the IBOutlets are all connected to the correct code (for the 2 original views). I cannot even connect the other IBOutlets to their respective code so I don't think that is the issue.

The issue is so bad I cannot even do the process with the ViewControllers that definitely can do it (the original 2 views).

All of them are definitely connected to the right ViewController using the Interface builder. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: ctrl click the component on the storyboard and delete all its connected references then try again

Comment: I tried that, and also made sure all the reconnected references are correct too. I really don't know where the issue is and I might just delete the new controllers that I made.

Comment: nope, go just write them manually and connect then to the ones you wrote .

Comment: I did what you asked me to and it seemed to work! Thanks! I also restarted my computed for good measure, maybe that helped too. In any case thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked that they're not connected to anything using `ctrl + click` then just write the injection code manually `@IBOutlet weak var foo: UIView!` then simply connect them to the one you already wrote.

Xcode sometimes have those issues, so it's not always a mistake you have done.

Comment: That's comforting to know because for the life of me I could not figure out what I did wrong. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: happy coding @danaq